# Generate Scala code from Antlr

Tags: scala, antlr

I used to use Antlr4, and hence the grammar generates the Lexer and Parser and all the classes in Java.
How can I make my ANTLR grammar generate Scala code instead of Java code !?

Comment: Have a look at [Combinator Parsing](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/combinator-parsing.html)

Comment: @zellus: OP wanted help with an ANTLR4 implementation, not advice to start over.

Comment: I thought Scala was supposed to integrate nicely with Java (I have no expertise here).  In that case, why couldn't OP simply integrate the ANTLR4 results with Scala?

Comment: @Ira Baxter why then choosing Scala and not leveraging its power features?

Comment: Why throw away a working solution? "Power features" doesn't trump "running".   If he said he wanted to do this in Scala and he was just starting, you answer might make sense.

Comment: Having a Scala target would enable generating JS code through ScalaJS. Although there is JS target for ANTLR, when it comes to processing syntax trees, I would rather write Scala code than JS.

Answer (score 3):

As of this moment, there is no Scala target for ANTLR v4 (nor is there one for v3).

Comment: Is this still valid statement that no Scala target [circa 2014 mid.]

Comment: @asyncwait, yes, as of this moment, ANTLR 4 has Java and C# targets, and JavaScript and Python 2 & 3 are being developed: https://github.com/antlr . ANTLR 3 is unlikely to get new targets.

Comment: @asyncwait It seems there is one now: https://github.com/bdkent/antlr4-scala-target

Comment: antlr4-scala-target project is dead

Comment: still no scala target?

Comment: @user1870400: nope.